# Understanding basic concept of object creation and reference variable

Tags: java, oop, object, reference

I have understanding whenever we say

```
a=b
```

it means whatever the value is in b it goes to a. In other words wherever b is referencing to it would now point to memory location of a.

Considering that when i say

```
a=b-----1)
b=a-----2)
```

what does this imply in terms of memory addressing and value stored in this memory location.

I know that the reference is being created in stack memory while object is getting created in heap memory. But I want to get a deeper understanding what is happening actually in each line of this code.

### Can someone please explain this basic concept of object creation and reference variable in more depth.

```
public class ABC
{
        public Object add(Object a, Object b)
         {
           a=new Object();
           b=new Object();
           a=b;
           b=a;
           System.out.println("a= "+a);
           System.out.println("b= "+b);    
           ABC c=new ABC();
           return c;
        }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
     {
       ABC cc=new ABC();
       Object c=cc.add(4,5);
       System.out.println("c= "+c);
     }
}
```

Comment: This is too broad. For such things you should read a book or a tutorial. If you have a specific problem with your code, you should explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Java always creates objects unless the fundamental ones on the heap and it keeps reference to that memory location on the stack. It then keeps track of all the reference to that memory location if the reference count become zero it destroys the object.

Now when you construct a and b they will have different references to two objects(because they are both constucted differently) but when you assign a to b a will have rhe reference to the second(b's) object making  the second line self assignment (because they have the same address in memory location).

Comment: a=new Obeject();     say object is being created at location ob500
b=new Obeject();     say object is being created at location ob700

Now what would it mean 1) a is now pointing at ob700 ?

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a primitive variable is different from initializing a reference variable, because primitive variables hold a specific value. For example;

```
    int i = 5;
    int j = 20;
    i = j;
    j = 15;
```

If you run this code, the "i" variable's value doesn't change because "i" holds "20". What changes is what the variable is "pointing" to. In other words, if you were to go and get the value for i, it would point to j, which is where the variable is.

But a reference show or hold an address which belongs to an object. For example

```
    1  Object a = new Object();
    2  Object b = new Object();
    3  a = b;
    4  b = a;
```

In the first and second line you create two objects. "a" and "b" are references used to track where their data is being held.

The third and fourth lines merely change the address of the object, not the actual attributes of it. They are aliases of one another, meaning that they are not necessarily two objects with the same values, but essentially the same object being pointed to with two different variables (a and b).